# SQL Server Interval and ::

Tags: sql, postgresql

I think I am dealing with some code from a SQL server script and I am just trying to understand what some of its doing:

1. My first question:

`(current_month - Interval '1 Month')::date as start_date,`

What is this line of code doing? Is the `Interval` a built in word in SQL?
What does the `::date` section mean?

2. My second question is pretty similar:

`select current_date::date as date`

What is this doing?

Sorry if these are basic questions I am new to this and could not find anything online.

Comment: that's not Sql Server syntax, looks more like postgresql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither of these are supported by SQL Server.

`interval` is standard SQL to support differences in date/time values.

`::` is syntax specific to Postgres and Postgres-derived databases.  It is equivalent to `cast()` or `convert()`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I was thinking it was something along that lines but thought I was dealing with SQL server. Cheers this has been really hellpful